# How to add one layout in between horizontal recyclerview list items

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview having horizontal orientation.
I want to add a view(1,2,3,4...) in between list items like below image. So Can anybody help me how to achieve that UI ?

Thanks in advance [image]

Comment: Drawing a circle "between" items isn't that complicated, but what determines the content of the circle? Is it always going to be a number? What defines the number? etc

Comment: @ss_ Did you get the solution for the above requirement? Please let me if you got it, I too have same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html).

> An ItemDecoration allows the application to add a special drawing and layout offset to specific item views from the adapter's data set. This can be useful for drawing dividers between items, highlights, visual grouping boundaries and more.

You will probably have to override `ItemDecoration#getItemOffsets` in order to position your view appropriately.

```
@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, int itemPosition, RecyclerView parent) {
    if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL_LIST)
        // set outRect offsets here
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?